# Issues with links on viewport change to mobile

Tags: html, magento2, viewport

having some issues with getting this Magento 2 site to be responsive... It's basically there but there are two blocks where there is a link which becomes unclickable after changing the viewport or looking at it on a mobile device

This is the site: https://typhoonairsoft.co.uk

Here is the code:

```
<div class="banner banner-col clearfix">
    <div class="banner-inner-content banner-inner-1 clearfix">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="wall-col">
                <div class="category-grid-item">
                    <div class="category-grid-item-wrap">
                        <div class="category-grid-featured-wrap">
                            <div class="category-grid-featured" style="background-image: url(//typhoonairsoft.co.uk/images/Galery-6.jpg);">
                            <span class="hidden">hidden</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-grid-featured-summary">
                        <div class="category-grid-featured-summary-wrap">
                            <h3><small>THE BEST</small> AIRSOFT GUNS</h3>
                            <a class="product-category-grid-btn" href="https://typhoonairsoft.co.uk/airsoft-gun.html">Shop Now</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wall-col box-ft box-ft-1">
            <div class="category-grid-item">
                <div class="category-grid-item-wrap">
                    <div class="category-grid-featured-wrap">
                        <div class="category-grid-featured" style="background-image: url(//typhoonairsoft.co.uk/images/00002188.png);"><span class="hidden">hidden</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-grid-featured-summary">
                        <div class="category-grid-featured-summary-wrap">
                            <h3><small>ACCESSORIES</small> GET TACTICAL</h3>
                            <a class="product-category-grid-btn" href="/tactical-gear.html">Shop Now</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have a `::before` pseudo element that overlays the entire block and causes the link to be "not clickable" as in "not reachable" through the layer of the `::before` element.

You can see it when you inspect your page. Looks like:

```
<div class="category-grid-item-wrap">
   ::before
   ...
```

Look at styles.css:1288 and you will find following CSS which is causing the `::before`:

```
.banner-inner-content .inner-wrapper .category-grid-item-wrap:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Weird, I have removed this line from the style.css and redeployed the static content but it's still coming up in the inspect element... Any ideas?

Comment: Try clearing directories manually via `rm -rf <magento-root>/pub/static/* <magento-root>/var/cache/* <magento-root>/var/page_cache/* <magento-root>/var/view_preprocessed/* <magento-root>/generated/*` . Adapt paths if you have different structure and redeploy after.